# Is there Javascript driver support for YCQL JSONB type in YugaByte DB?

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

We are trying to use JSONB of YugaByte’s YCQL (Cassandra) API. We were able to insert using the node’s Cassandra-driver but have not able to SELECT the JSONB column back.  It looks like we are hitting the issue mentioned here: https://github.com/YugaByte/yugabyte-db/issues/778.

Is support for JSONB in the Javascript driver coming soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this support (for JSONB type in YCQL) is available in YugabyteDB's version of the nodejs driver.

https://github.com/yugabyte/cassandra-nodejs-driver